# why some http requests are showing no response data in j meter?

Tags: jmeter

When I run a Http Request, to a page that should return a response body. When I execute the sampler it's sends a 200 OK code, but the response body in the View Results Tree Listener, is empty. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It does happen because the system under test doesn't send any response body so you're asking the wrong people about the possible reasons.

If you can reproduce is with the real browser or other tool like [curl](https://curl.se/) - you need to raise an issue against the system you're testing because it must be functionally stable before you can start executing performance tests.

If you cannot reproduce it with a real browser - make sure to [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), i.e. add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and set it up to send the same [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) that the browser does.